# Comparing simple features {sf} and Spatial objects {sp}: speed and memory

Tags: r, intersection, r-sp, r-sf

I'm using some spatial data in R, and wondering whether use the packages/functions that rely on the old Spatial format (package sp) or the new package sf. I made this test, based on code found [here](https://lbusettspatialr.blogspot.it/2018/02/speeding-up-spatial-analyses-by.html?m=1).

The idea is to "identify all points falling within a maximum distance of xx meters with respect to each single point in a spatial points dataset".

```
library(tictoc)

# define a buffer distance and a toy data
maxdist <- 500
df<-data.frame(x = runif(10000, 0, 100000),y = runif(10000, 0, 100000),id = 1:10000)

# doing the analysis using sf
library(sf)
tic("sf")
pts     <- df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"))
pts_buf <- st_buffer(pts, maxdist,nQuadSegs = 5)
int     <- st_intersects(pts_buf, pts)
toc()

# doing the analysis using sp
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
tic("sp")
pts2      <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(df[,1:2],as.data.frame(df[,3]))
pts_buf2  <- gBuffer(pts2, byid=TRUE,width=maxdist)
int2      <- over(pts_buf2, pts2,returnList = TRUE)
toc()

# size of the objects
object.size(pts)<object.size(pts2)
object.size(pts_buf)<object.size(pts_buf2)
```

Using sf seems to be much better as faster (around 0.53 vs 2.1 seconds in my machine) and requiring less memory. There is one exception though. Why object *pts* is much larger than *pts2*? Is sf less efficient in storing a vector of points?

Answer (score 4):

One reason I can think of:

The `pts` (`sf`) object keeps an attribute specifying the 'type' of geometry object for **every row**. This is because every row has the potential to be a different geometry in an `sf` object.

Whereas the `pts2` (`sp`) is in an object of class `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. It can only hold points, so there's no need to keep the extra attribute for each 'row'

Take the first two rows of the `sf` object as an example, these are the attributes associated with those geometries

```
lapply(1:2, function(x) attributes(st_geometry(pts[x, ])))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$names
# [1] "1"
# 
# [[1]]$class
# [1] "sfc_POINT" "sfc"      
# 
# [[1]]$precision
# [1] 0
# 
# [[1]]$bbox
# xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
# 81647.16 72283.90 81647.16 72283.90 
# 
# [[1]]$crs
# Coordinate Reference System: NA
# 
# [[1]]$n_empty
# [1] 0
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$names
# [1] "2"
# 
# [[2]]$class
# [1] "sfc_POINT" "sfc"      
# 
# [[2]]$precision
# [1] 0
# 
# [[2]]$bbox
# xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
# 5591.116 38967.060  5591.116 38967.060 
# 
# [[2]]$crs
# Coordinate Reference System: NA
# 
# [[2]]$n_empty
# [1] 0
```

Every row of this `sf` data.frame will have similar attributes.

If you strip the attributes from the geometries (to just leave a data.frame)

```
pts_coords <- st_coordinates(pts)
pts_striped <- pts
st_geometry(pts_striped) <- NULL
pts_striped <- cbind(pts_striped, pts_coords)
```

And then compare the object sizes

```
object.size(pts_striped)
# 200896
object.size(pts2)
# 203624
```

The objects are much closer aligned in size

Comment: Thank you @SymbolixAU, this is something. Although not clear why the sf object, after buffer, becomes smaller than the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame